# Скрытие сайдбара и заполнение его области

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox, media-queries

Народ, привет. Есть блок сайдбара и блок контента. Через медиа запрос сайдбар скрывается методом убирания его влево, но основной блок контента остается на своем же месте. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы он занимал место сайдбара, т.е. растягивался на всю ширину. Если применить просто display: none сайдбару, то все норм, но тогда не будет этой анимации скрывания.

P.s. Камнями плиз не кидайтесь, только начинаю изучать нормально фронт.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $dark;
  color: $primary;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  flex-basis: 285px;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  @include breakpoint(lg) {
    transform: translateX(-285px);
  }
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</body>
```

Всем спасибо.

Comment: при определенной ширине экрана делайте сайдбару width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;  а главному блоку width:100%

Comment: Так получается нет анимации когда скрывается блок sidebar, а хотелось бы чтобы она осталась

Comment: в таком случае в ваш код сайдбару попробуйте добавить overflow: hidden;  а главному блоку max-width:100% или width:max-content;

Comment: @Arcadiy если играть с шириной блока, во время схлопывания этого самого блока, будет весьма неприятно наблюдать картину, как вся инфа внутри блока, особенно текст, перескакивают со строки на строку подстраиваясь под новую ширину.

Comment: @Pilaton чтобы сделать по-другому недостаточно предоставленной информации

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(() => {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('hidden');
}, 1000);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $dark;
  color: $primary;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #ffd8d8;
  transition-property: margin-left;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 150ms;
  width: 285px;
  /*
  @include breakpoint(lg) {
    margin-left: -285px;
  }
  */
}

.content {
  background: #fff5c3;
  flex: auto;
}

/* for demo */
body.hidden .sidebar {
  margin-left: -285px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Да, так отлично. Спасибо за такой вариант. Насколько это правильно во фронте?

Comment: @ramiscoder Я не знаю, что у вас в целом там наверстано. Может можно сделать лучше, а может и нельзя. Вы хотели плавно скрывающийся блок сайдбара с попутно растягивающимся блоком контента, я сделал.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в классе `.content` немного не правильно задано свойство `flex`. Flex - это сокращенная запись трёх свойств: `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` и `flex-basis`.

Попробуйте исправить так:

```
.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Comment: Так тоже не работает.